magento 2.4.6 replace Zend_Http_UserAgent_Mobile with laminas
I'm in the process of migrating my magento 2.4.4 to magento 2.4.6. This version of magento removed some Zend classes and replaced them with laminas. I've been able to fix my custom code almost entirely, my only issue is the Zend_Http_UserAgent_Mobile class which keeps throwing errors. How can I replace this class (which no longer exists in magento) with a laminas-compatible one?

what function you are using from this class Zend_Http_UserAgent_Mobile

You can replace this  Zend_Http_UserAgent_Mobile to Laminas\Http\Header\UserAgent
Reference URL : https://olegkrivtsov.github.io/laminas-api-reference/html/classes/Laminas/Http/Header/UserAgent.html
